# Can't send ethernet packages across my LAN

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy

I am playing around with scapy (module for Python). I want to build packages and send them across my local network from one host to another. When I buil my package like that, I do not receive anything on my destination host:

`packet = Ether() / IP(dst='192.168.0.6') / TCP(dport=8000)` => `sendp(packet)`.

However, when I build it like that it works: `packet = IP(dst='192.168.0.6') / TCP(dport=8000)`, `send(packet)`.

I capture the packages on my destination host with the help of wireshark.

Why doesn't the Ethernet-Variant work? I have all my PCs connected with ethernet cables...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you on a wireless network or a wired network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send()` uses Scapy's routing table (which is copied from the host's routing table when Scapy is started), while `sendp()` uses the provided interface, or `conf.iface` when no value is specified.

So you should either set `conf.iface = [iface]` (`[iface]` being the interface you want to use), or specify `sendp([...], iface=[iface])`.

Comment: Thank you @Pierre! I used `sendp(ethernet_packet, iface=MyIface)` and everything worked just fine.